# Activating python bot without mouse interruption

Tags: python, virtual-machine, mouse, bluestacks

I have developed a software in python that automatically clicks patterns on top of Bluestacks.
right now the software steals my mouse cursor and i cant use my computer regularly.
i have tried running Bluestacks inside a virtual machine for it to have its own mouse but it didn't work out. any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some information about your host OS and/or the VM information. If you're using VirtualBox, you could try to generate a "host key" (by default, the right Ctrl key, on MacOS, the left Command key) press event to take out the mouse pointer from your virtual machine

Comment: I think u didn't get me right, I've tried running Bluestacks ( android emulator ) on virtualbox in order to have 2 mouses my os on host is windows10 and os on virtualbox vm is windows10 aswell